# SQLAlchemy and polymorphic inheritance with backrefs

Tags: inheritance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, polymorphism, backreference

I have the classes `Node` and `Leaf (Node)` as shown below: It works fine, but I'd prefer to shift the `leafs` and `subleafs` definitions to the `Leaf (Node)` class. How do I achieve that?

```
class Node (db.Model):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'node', 'polymorphic_on':'type'}
    id = db.Column (db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column ('type', db.String (16))

    root_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey (id))
    nodes = db.relationship ('Node',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Node.root_id==Node.id',
        backref=db.backref('root', remote_side=id))
    leafs = db.relationship ('Leaf',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Leaf.root_id==Node.id')

    base_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey (id))
    subnodes = db.relationship ('Node',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Node.base_id==Node.id',
        backref=db.backref('base', remote_side=id))
    subleafs = db.relationship ('Leaf',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Leaf.base_id==Node.id')

    def __init__ (self, root):
        self.base = root.base if root and root.base else root
        self.root = root
```

and

```
class Leaf (Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'leaf'}
    leaf_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey ('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__ (self, root):
        super (Leaf, self).__init__ (root)
```

I tried this, but failed (partially):

```
class Leaf (Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'leaf'}
    leaf_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey ('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    _x = db.relationship ('Node', backref=db.backref ('leafs',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic', primaryjoin='Leaf.root_id==Node.id'))
    _y = db.relationship ('Node', backref=db.backref ('subleafs',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic', primaryjoin='Leaf.base_id==Node.id'))

    def __init__ (self, root):
        super (Leaf, self).__init__ (root)
```

My **delete** test cases did not like this (just deleting the base/root node in the tree and relying on `cascade='all'`), and complained with:

```
CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. Cycles: set([DeleteState(<Leaf at 0x22789d0>)]) all edges: set([(DeleteState(<Leaf at 0x22789d0>), DeleteState(<Leaf at 0x22789d0>))])
```

The **reason** I want to shift the definitions is, because I do not want to extend `Node` with definitions for every sub-class of `Leaf (Node)`, which I might introduce later. Further, I definitely don't need `_x` and `_y`, since I already have `Leaf.root` and `Leaf.base` (provided by `Node`); but **omitting** them (`_x =` & `_y =`) called for trouble like:

```
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'leafs'
```

I guess I'm required to use *something* in `Leaf (Node)` to attach the relations to, even though I was not required to use any backrefs in my original definitions for `leafs` and `subleafs` in `Node`. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some trying I've found a solution, that is not perfect, but does the job: I just moved the `Node.leafs` and `Node.subleafs` definitions to the file `leaf.py` where `class Leaf (node)` has been defined and appended with the former definitions like below:

```
class Leaf (Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'leaf'}
    leaf_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey ('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__ (self, root):
        super (Leaf, self).__init__ (root)

Node.leafs = db.relationship (Leaf, cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
    primaryjoin=Node.id==Leaf.root_id)

Node.subleafs = db.relationship (Leaf, cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
    primaryjoin=Node.id==Leaf.base_id)
```

A disadvantage of this is that people have to `from models import Leaf` if they want to access `Node.leafs` and `Node.subleafs`, but since they had to do this anyway (even if `Node.leafs` and `Node.subleafs` had been defined as backrefs within `class Leaf (Node)`), it is allright.

If somebody finds a solution, where the relationships are defined as backrefs within `class Leaf (Node)`, I'd be glad to hear from; thx.